# Best practice to create large web applications with multiple views, many components and nemory issues

Tags: java, vaadin

I am not sure how I should best structure my Vaadin Web application.

Assuming in my web application, we have many different `View` objects with each lots of components. The components never change, but the data in the components changes upon every page enter.

I am seeing two possibilities:

1. Create and initialize all the objects once in the View's constructor. When the View's `enter(ViewChangeEvent event)` gets called, bind the data to the already existing objects.
2. Do nothing in the View's constructor. Create all the components in the `enter(ViewChangeEvent event)` method, bind the data to these components.

Simplified example of the two different approaches:

public class OneView extends VerticalLayout implements View{

```
private TextField[] textfields = new TextField[VaadinprojectUI.TESTLIMIT];

public OneView() {
    long startMs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    for (int i=0;i<VaadinprojectUI.TESTLIMIT;i++){
        TextField txtField = new TextField("Textfield #" + i);
        textfields[i] = txtField;
        addComponent(txtField);
    }
    long finishMs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("OneView() - constructor" + (finishMs - startMs));
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    long startMs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    for (int i=0;i<VaadinprojectUI.TESTLIMIT;i++){
        textfields[i].setValue((String.valueOf(Math.random()*1000)));
    }
    long finishMs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("OneView - enter()" + (finishMs - startMs));
}
```

OneView will first create 1000 TextFields, add them to the VerticalLayout, and store them in an array for reuse. When OneView is navigated to, it will bind the data to the textfields.

```
public class TwoView extends VerticalLayout implements View{

    public TwoView() {
        //nothing in the constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        long startMs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        //entire load is in the "enter", only called upon navigation. 
        for (int i=0;i<VaadinprojectUI.TESTLIMIT;i++){
            TextField txtField = new TextField("Textfield #" + i);
            txtField.setValue((String.valueOf(Math.random()*1000)));
            addComponent(txtField);
        }
        long finishMs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("TwoView - enter()" + (finishMs - startMs));
    }
```

TwoView will not do anything in the constructor, but whenever it is navigated to, it will create 1000 TextFields, and bind the data to them. The textfields are not stored, and will be remade at another time.

**Some testing, navigating back and forth:**

```
OneView() - constructor32
OneView - enter()14
TwoView - enter()28
OneView - enter()5
TwoView - enter()18
OneView - enter()3
TwoView - enter()12
```

Upon starting the application, OneView takes some time to create its TextFields. But after that, it always does a faster job to bind the data to its TextFields (which is expected).

Questions:

- What are the tradeoffs with using the OneView system when it comes to memory management? Can we freely create View after View in large applications? I have a real world Vaadin application where we are getting OutOfMemoryErrors, and I feel maybe it's because I am reserving so much space for reusable components
- What happens when the page is left? In TwoView, I assume the Garbage Collection destroys everything and frees up the memory. In OneView, the TextFields remain in the memory with the data assigned to them. Is there something as an "exit()" event when the user leaves the View that we should use to clear the data in the components? I am thinking in cases of ComboBoxes or tables with lots of Objects in them, but that don't get cleared upon page leaving and clog up the memory because they won't get GC'd?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Did you make and analyze a heap dump from your real world Vaadin application that has the memory problems? You should be able to see where most of the memory is in use. Would be interesting to see how much memory each user session consumes.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one of the questions which are best answered with: It depends...

When you pre-create all potential vaadin elements, and then bind/unbind them on View enter/leave, you will have better performance.

From the memory point of view, it might get ugly, when you have 1000 instances of the view "preloaded" but only 4-5 actively used...

If you however reuse the same view/components many many times, this will be better from the memory GC point of view.

The better way would be to create the elemnts as needed, **and** remove/free them as soon as possible.

When you corretcly remove all references to the vaadin components, the GC should trigger before a OOM exception is thrown.

Since you actually see OOM, this suggests that you don't free resources in a timely fashion. (Or perhaps your memory is just too small for what you wish to do)

Comment: I have experimented further, and realized there are objects I would like (or have expected GC to take care of) that don't get taken care of. For instance, a Table in a view, that I fill up with complex objects -- when the user navigates away from a full table, the items are still there. As the Table is still there, and it's still on the VerticalLayout, which is part of the View. I feel like the View class misses an "exit()" or "leave()" method I could override in which I could call removeAllItems() to allow those complex objects to be Garbage Collected

Comment: The Navigator fires viewChange Events before/after nav changes. https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.0/com/vaadin/navigator/Navigator.html#addViewChangeListener-com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener-

Answer (score 1):

When you add a view to a Navigator you can either add a class you've created like this:

```
Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
navigator.addView("viewStuff", new ViewStuff());
```

Or you can add the view and refer the the class instead

```
navigator.addView("viewStuff", ViewStuff.class);
```

This way the navigator creates a new class each time one is required. I chose this method as we have a lot of views and didn't really want a load of view created that may never even get used.